# Having problems with \headheight in LaTeX R-Markdown (inconsistent page layout)

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I'm currently having an issue with latex in Rmarkdown (using fancyhdr package). I am trying to make a data report with a certain template style. But as of right now, my heading1 for each page is not aligned properly. I assume it has something to do with my \headheight, but I am not sure how to resolve it.

This is currently done in R-markdown, and I am quite confident that the issue has something to do with my YAML. I would be very appreciated if anyone could tell me how to fix my YAML coding for \headheight or overall improving my coding for YAML to fix the overlapping issue.

There are no errors when I run this code, but this is the warnings that they provide me (but I have no idea how to resolve the warning)

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 32.08571pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

This is my YAML:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
header-includes:|
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \newcommand{\helv}{%
    \fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
  \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo.png}}
  \fancyhead[L]{\textbf\selectfont\sffamily{Daily Report}}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\textbf\selectfont\sffamily{NOT INTENDED FOR FORWARDING}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
classoption: a4paper
---
```

And these are in the rest of the codes:

````
```r-markdown

## \selectfont\sffamily{EQUITY 1}

# content page 1 

\newpage

## \selectfont\sffamily{EQUITY 2} 

# content page 2
````

I posted an image of the pdf output on TeXStackExchange: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482525/having-problems-with-latex-coding-in-rmarkdown-fancyhdr-headheight

I would like all of them to be aligned with each other. I do not know if I have done my coding in YAML correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is pretty explicit that the headheight needs to be larger than 32.08571pt. This requirement can be fulfilled by adding e.g. `\setlength{\headheight}{32.09pt}` to your header-includes.

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
header-includes:|
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \newcommand{\helv}{%
    \fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
  \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo.png}}
  \fancyhead[L]{\textbf\selectfont\sffamily{Daily Report}}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\textbf\selectfont\sffamily{NOT INTENDED FOR FORWARDING}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \setlength{\headheight}{32.09pt}
classoption: a4paper
---
```

Comment: If i ignore this kinda warning, will it affect while parsing the resume in ATS or something?

Comment: @SafinGhoghabori No idea what an ATS might be

Comment: ATS is Application Tracking System. If you are applying to companies you must be knowing. Nowadays companies use ATS to track and parse resumes of candidates. You can google it. I just wanted to know about these warnings and errors are harmful or not.